# Case insensitive swear filter outputting string with bad words in bold in original input case

Tags: php, arrays, replace, str-replace

I have the following code which I want to use as a swear filter.

```
<?php 

    $replace = array( 
    'dog' => '***', 
    'apple' => '*****',
    'chevy' => '*****' 
    ); 

    $string = 'I like dog to eat an Apple with my Dog in my Chevy'; 

    echo strReplaceAssoc($replace,$string); 

    function strReplaceAssoc(array $replace, $subject) { 
       return str_ireplace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $subject);    
    } 

    // Result: I like *** to eat an ***** with my *** in my *****

?>
```

I need to adapt this though, to create an alternate result where the bad word is highlighted (wrapped in strong tags) rather than starred out and I also need to keep the original casing of the word inputted by the user.

So my result would be something like:

```
I like <strong>dog</strong> to eat as <strong>Apple</strong> with my <strong>Dog</strong> in my <strong>Chevy</strong>
```

Is there an easy way to adapt my code to do this?

**EDIT!!!!!**

Here's the best solution I have come up with so far:

```
$replace = array( 
    'dog', 
    'apple',
    'chevy' 
); 

$string = 'I like dog to eat an Apple with my Dog in my Chevy Chevy chevy'; 

function filterwords($text, array $filterWords){
    $filterCount = sizeof($filterWords);
    for($i=0; $i<$filterCount; $i++){
        $text = preg_replace('/\b'.$filterWords[$i].'\b/ie',"str_repeat('*',strlen('$0'))",$text);
    }
    return $text;
}

function strReplace($subject, array $blacklist) {
    return array_reduce($blacklist, function ($r, $v) {
         return $r = preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($v, '/').')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $r);
    }, $subject);
}

echo filterwords($string, $replace); 
echo '<br />';
echo strReplace($string, $replace);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) in conjunction with `str_ireplace`. So the code will look like this:

```
function strReplace(array $blacklist, $subject) {
    return array_reduce($blacklist, function ($r, $v) {
        return $r = str_ireplace($v, "<strong>$v</strong>", $r);
    }, $subject);
}

$blacklist = array( 
    'dog',
    'apple',
    'chevy',
);

$string = 'I like dog to eat an Apple with my Dog in my Chevy'; 

$result = strReplace($blacklist, $string);
```

**Update:**

`strReplace` version for retaining bad words' case:

```
function strReplace(array $blacklist, $subject) {
        return array_reduce($blacklist, function ($r, $v) {
                return $r = preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($v, '/').')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $r);
        }, $subject);
}
```

Comment: I like it, except it does not retain the casing of the bad word when it wraps it.

Comment: @Tom Then you have to use `preg_replace`. See the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

EDIT with new solution based on comments:

```
function replaceWords($str, $star = true){

$replace = array(
"/(dog)/i",
"/(cat)/i"
);

if ($star){
    $with = '***';
} else {
    $with = '<strong>$1</strong>';
}

return preg_replace($replace, $with, $str);

}



echo replaceWords("I like dog and cat and duck.");
echo replaceWords("I like dog and cat and duck", false);

/* Results: I like *** and *** and duck.I like <strong>dog</strong> and <strong>cat</strong> and duck */
```

Comment: That doesn't wrap 'Dog' or 'DoG' in strong tags.

Comment: I like it! But that messes up my existing method of ****ing out the words. I need both methods to work - preferably using the same array of bad words

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean. You want it to use both at once? E.g. <strong>***</strong> ???

Comment: Sorry! Not so good at explaining myself! I have some places where I need to replace the bad word with ***** and other places where it needs to just be highlighted. So I need to accommodate both functionalities. I'll add my current solution to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer for you. It's just one function to call, with either true or false as whether you want to replace with stars or <strong> tags